# Building icsopenvpn

Tags: android-ndk, openvpn

I have some issues in building `ics-openvpn` project. When I deploy the app on the device and try to import a `.ovpn` file, I get `cannot find minivpn`. I think this error is related to an error during the app building.

I've downloaded android NDK and set the path in Eclipse, downloaded cygwin and launched `./build-native.sh`, but it returns me the error

`./build-native.sh: line 1: ndk-build: command not found`

I've tried to modify the path in the .sh with the path of ndk-build, but I get another error:

`NON-CYGWIN COMPATIBLE MAKE PROGRAM.....`

Anyone knows what steps I have to follow to properly build the project?

Answer (score 1):

You should not try to build it with the cygwin. There is also a `build-native.bat` in the project which allows the project to be build with windows. Make sure that you have installed the ndk and ndk-build is in your PATH.

Comment: I run .bat, and ndk is in the PATH,but now I get the following output:

C:\Users\Vincenzo\ics-openvpn>call ndk-build -j 8
Impossibile trovare il percorso specificato.
Sottodirectory o file ..\assets già esistente.
Impossibile trovare il file specificato.
Impossibile trovare C:\Users\Vincenzo\ics-openvpn\.hg\libcrypto.so
Impossibile trovare C:\Users\Vincenzo\ics-openvpn\.hg\libssl.so
Impossibile trovare il file specificato.
Impossibile trovare C:\Users\Vincenzo\ics-openvpn\src\libcrypto.so
Impossibile trovare C:\Users\Vincenzo\ics-openvpn\src\libssl.so

Comment: From google translate error message is "System cannot find the path specified." which means ndk-build is probably not in your path. Try just ndk-build in the ics-openvpn directory. That should give the same error that the command cannot be found.

Comment: yes, I've already tried and the error is the same, but in environment variables I added to PATH the correct path to android ndk.
If I try to run ndk-build from the directory where it's stored I get the same error.
Maybe I have to set the path somewhere else?

Comment: Then you have same problem with your NDK. Try posting a question concerning the non working ndk-build command. This has nothing to do with OpenVPN for Android anymore

Comment: I solved the ndk issue, but now, when I run build-native.bat i get:

C:\Users\Vincenzo\ics-openvpn\jni>cd..

C:\Users\Vincenzo\ics-openvpn>build-native.bat

C:\Users\Vincenzo\ics-openvpn>call ndk-build -j 8
jni/Android.mk:12: google-breakpad/android/google_breakpad/Android.mk: No such f
ile or directory
jni/Android.mk:12: google-breakpad/android/google_breakpad/Android.mk: No such f
ile or directory
jni/Android.mk:12: google-breakpad/android/google_breakpad/Android.mk: No such f
ile or directory
make: *** No rule to make target `google-breakpad/android/google_breakpad/Androi
d.mk'.  Stop.

Answer (score 1):

Run build-native.bat 
make sure you must have NDK 8b and set the environment variable for the ndk file